# How to edit a specific username, password, and email on a database based on what account your logged in with

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to have a page in which a user, when logged in, can edit their username/password/email, but am having difficulty in understanding any way in which to do this easily; I am new to PHP and SQL. I know this version of SQL is deprecated, but I am not building this for security, so I am not concerned with SQL injection attacks at the moment.

This is my login code currently.

```
<?PHP
 $uname = "";
    $pword = "";
    $errorMessage = "";
    $num_rows = 0;

    //==========================================
    //  ESCAPE DANGEROUS SQL CHARACTERS
    //==========================================
    function quote_smart($value, $handle) {

       if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
           $value = stripslashes($value);
       }

       if (!is_numeric($value)) {
           $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
       }
       return $value;
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $pword = $_POST['password'];

        $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
        $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);

        //==========================================
        //  CONNECT TO THE LOCAL DATABASE
        //==========================================
        $user_name = "root";
        $pass_word = "";
        $database = "login";
        $server = "127.0.0.1";

        $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
        $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

        if ($db_found) {

            $uname = quote_smart($uname, $db_handle);
            $pword = quote_smart($pword, $db_handle);

            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 = $uname AND L2 = $pword";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        //====================================================
        //  CHECK TO SEE IF THE $result VARIABLE IS TRUE
        //====================================================

            if ($result) {
                if ($num_rows > 0) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
                    header ("Location: Logged.php");
                }
                else {
                    echo "<script> alert('Invalid Login')</script>";
                }   
            }
            else {
                echo "<script> alert('Invalid Login')</script>";    
            }

        mysql_close($db_handle);

        }                   
    }    
?>
```

This will then take you to a page called logged.php, which will contain forms for the user to enter in the new username, password, and email they want to use, but I don't know how to make it able to actually edit a database entry and, secondly, to edit the correct entry.

The database columns currently are ID, L1, L2 and Email. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: SQL injections aside, why would you want to learn with a deprecated method when you can learn with a new method instead? That's like someone buying a manual transmission in their first car today.

Comment: @TylerH there's nothing wrong with a manual transmission, this is like trying to train for your driver's license in a horse and carriage.

Comment: wouldn't it just be a matter of ding an update to the database where the ID is equal to the user Id of the logged person ? (i mean, you have that information since you did a "select *" on your users table.

Comment: @Sammitch It's a deprecated, less efficient method, pure and simple, and a much closer analogy than yours. Your analogy would better fit someone trying to use several tables drawn on a chalk board vs a SQL database.